# How to put a comma instead of "and" between the name of the authors in LaTeX with revtex4

Tags: article, revtex

I'm facing some problem in my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,pra,aps,showpacs,reprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,amsbsy,color,graphicx,bm,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%Para usar pt-br com RevTex4
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
% Para indentar o primeiro parágrafo
\usepackage{indentfirst}


\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
        \title{ \Large{Title} %english title
        \\      \large{subtitle}}
        \author{ person 1 }
        \email{email  1}  
        \author{ person 2 }
        \email{email 2}
        

        \affiliation{affiliation}

\end{document}
```

When I run this code, I get the authors' names as "person 1 **and** person 2", but I want it to be "person 1, person 2", with a comma between the names. How can I do this?

Comment: Untested: `\renewcommand{\andname}{,}`.

Comment: Consider using `revtex4-2`. If this is for a submission to a journal, you should restrain from instructions such as `\Large` in the title.